# find type of object in overridden new (and delete)

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to add some memory debugging to an existing application.

I have overridden global new/delete operators to keep track of memory allocation:

is it possible from within these operators to find the type of the object being new'd?

very primitively something like:

```
void * operator new(std::size_t n)
{
    void *p = malloc(n);
    printf("%p new %s (%d)\n", p, **TYPEOFOBJECT**, n);
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void * p)
{
    printf("%p del %s\n", p, **TYPEOFTHING**);
    free(p);
}
```

which would then display:

```
MyObject *obj = new MyObject;

0x5555555555555555 new NewObject (24);
```

Comment: `operator new` doesn’t know what type is being created, just its size.

Comment: Not with your approach (the global operators can be called directly, not just when creating an object).  Can you overload the operators for the classes you care about?

Comment: While you can override per class, it would not be scalable as you would have to write it for each and every type. Using a function similar to `make_unique` would allows you to print the type.

Comment: Hi, I wanted a way to be able catch every new/delete, not just for my classes, also, I was hoping there was going to be a quick-fix general solution without needing code in every class. (I am tracking 'malloc' and 'free' tracking with some macros and __LINE__ __FUNCTION__)